# Catalog price rules vs. shopping cart price rules

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules, price-rules

I'm setting up price rules, but cannot get it to work like I want.

I want to give all logged in customers 5% discount (preferably shown in the catalog with catalog price rules), but if one of these logged in customers get a discount code with 35% discount, the discount code should overwrite the "standard" discount, not stack.

As I understand, **Catalog price rules** and **Shopping Cart price rules** run seperate priorities, right?

I have tried setting up 2 **Shopping Cart price rules**:
Priority 0, 35% discount, Stop Further Rules Processing = yes
Priority 1, 5% discount, Stop Further Rules Processing = no

My problem is now, that when adding different products to the cart, the system only gives 35% discount to the first product...

How to get these rules running as described in the top?

[image]